# Cannot create inner bean, SpringBatch

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-data, spring-batch

Por favor su ayuda como soluciono este error al ejecutar un Job en la lectura de una archivo XML con SpringBatch: cannot create inner bean (inner bean)#4097d7fe of type [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.StateTransition] while setting bean property 'stateTransitions' with key[0] nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationAxception

**-> bean.xml**

```
<bean id="xmlItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="file:///#{jobParameters['inputFile']}/AMP-Camt53.xml"></property>
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="AMP" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="customUnmarshaller" />
</bean>

<bean id="customUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.bbva.pkre.dto.accounting.amp.AMP</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="xmlItemProcessor" class="com.bbva.pkre.batch.process.AMPItemProcess" />
<bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="com.bbva.pkre.batch.writer.AMPItemWriter" />
```

**-> context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">
  <job id="PCTXJ003-01-PE" incrementer="defaultIncrementer" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <description>Job to process traslate and dave of file camt53</description>
    <listeners>
      <listener ref="interceptorJobExecutionListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <step id="step">
      <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="idFileReader" processor="idFileProcesor" writer="idFileWriter" commit-interval="2"></chunk>
      </tasklet>
    </step>
  </job>
</beans:beans>
```

**Log de error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ahí más abajo se alcaaaaanza a ver que no puede encontrar la clase StaxEventItemReader. Será que te falta definir alguna dependencia?

Comment: Si revise las dependencias y tengo las necesarias, podría ser posible que el error se de por la configuración que he realizo o por alguna configuración que falte?

Comment: Por favor vea  [edit] tu pregunta y añade info. Sin ver el POM, es imposible decirlo. Lo otro: La clave de un stacktrace Java está en que, entre más abajo vas en un mismo evento registrado, más a fondo llegas en la causa. Te sugiero que veas la versión texto-plano de ese log y pongas acá un fragmento más extenso del mismo, que para este issue pongas todos los `Caused by:` hasta que vuelva y ponga un evento diferente (para cada evento registrado en log, logger siempre pone el timestamp con fecha y hora).

Comment: Como menciona @Alfabravo, por favor, adjunta el stacktrace completo a texto, de manera que pueda leerse.

Comment: Ya agregue mas detalle y el log mas extenso, solo comparte la parte superior porque mostraba el: "Cannot create inner bean"